# Delphi: Main form icon not changing with application icon

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have a tray application that monitors a Windows service. Depending on the status of the Windows Service, I change the **application icon** to either a green, orange or red LED.

My default application icon is the red LED (Project -> Options -> Application -> Icons).

All the icons change except the icon of the main form, that does not change. The following icons does change:

1. Tray icon [image]
2. Taskbar icon when maximized [image]
3. Icons of all other forms [image]

**What do I need to do to get the main form icon to change?**

I have even explicitly change the frmMain.Icon but that also did not work.

My code is simple and looks like this:

```
    {set the application icon}
    if FAppStatus = Error then
      ImageList.GetIcon(2, Application.Icon)
    else
    if FAppStatus = Warning then
      ImageList.GetIcon(1, Application.Icon)
    else
      ImageList.GetIcon(0, Application.Icon);
    frmMain.Icon := Application.Icon;
```

I have tried different BorderStyles but that made no difference.
I also played with Application.MainFormOnTaskbar without success.

**Moderator:** Please note that this question is NOT about the taskbar icon.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. You would have to provide [mcve]

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar - hmmmm, I wrote a little app to demonstrate my problem and I couldn't reproduce it either. That made me think... I took out the TStyleManager and everything worked like it should.

Comment: Answer: I use a TStyleManager and was setting it in the project source (.dpr) before I create my main form. I moved it to AFTER creating the main form and now my program works fine.